# Insert string to PDF with For loop

Tags: php, loops, fpdi

I'm a junior PHP developer.
For a costumer I need to place some strings into a pdf. I'm using [FPDI](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/) and I like it.
I have an existing template PDF and I need to insert every characters of a string into a little graphic box (*see image*).

[image: example]

Every characters must have 2 millimeters (*`8px` approximately*) from each others.

Every strings can have different length, so I thought do like this:

```php
$name = 'namenamename';
$stringcount = strlen($name)-1;
$countspace = $stringcount*2;
//121 = coordinate of first box
for ($x=121; $x <= $x+$countspace; $x = $x+2) {
  for ($i=0; $i <= $stringcount; $i++) {        
    $pdf->SetXY($x, 37);
    $pdf->Write(0,$name[$i]);
  }
}
```

That doesn't work. This is the error:

> Maximum execution time of 30 seconds

Can you help me please with the correct approach and with good explanation for a newbie? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
    $name = 'namenamename';
$string_length = strlen($name);

$coordinate = 121; //Give to the variable coordinate the beginning value, in this case 121
for ($i=0; $i < $string_length; $i++){ //make only one loop for the string length so the loop ends when there is no more characters


    $char = substr($name,$i,1); // this is "the tricky part", with substr you can grab each character with its position in the string
    $pdf -> SetXY($coordinate, 37); // here you put the coordinate for the character
    $pdf -> Write(0, $char); // write it
    $coordinate += 2; // and increment it by two, since the character are two spaces away from each other
}
```

hope that will help..

Comment: Really really thanks ManoS! This was my first time with For Loop and your answer really help me to understand the logic.

Comment: I'm so glad that I helped you :) no problem, keep up the good work buddy, and try to code and learn as much as possible and every day you will be better then you was yesterday ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not a great solution but you can modify the execution time with this line of code

set_time_limit ( $seconds );

Anyway give it a try but i think that is more an error in the logic of the loop maybe.

Can you say exactly the coordinate where you need the two first characters, the first is 121 + something or 121?

Comment: ok i don't know if you have already solved it or not but i'm gonne give you an example :)